# How to Share JS Variable values between Razor .cshtml and Html file (a Html solution in the same solution)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, razor

I have a MVC Razor solution in which I have a separate HTML project(folder name **Sub_HtmlProject** from the attachment).

**Question:** How to use a JavaScript variable **'razorJSVar'** defined in this Razor **_Layout.cshtml**
`Views > Shared > _Layout.cshtml`

**To:**

`Sub_HtmlProject > index.html`

Please note I would like to have a solution without using LocalStorage, Session, DB storage or any browser storage options.

[image]**

Comment: By share do you mean by two different pages (in separate browser tabs)?

Comment: where you rendered or called index.html in this application?

Answer (score 2):

Developer_29,

The issue is that you need to make index.html into index.cshtml and use the layout on that index.cshtml page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Layout.cs class

```
public class _Layout
{
    private _Layout() { }


    public static _Layout GetTestVarHere()
    {
        _Layout layoutModel = new _Layout();
        layoutModel.Name = "testStringValue";
        return layoutModel;
    }


    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Call from Index.html like -

```
 @{

    var razorJSVar = Shared._Layout.GetTestVarHere();
}
```

Use in your index.html